# Tableau change data source extract location

Tags: tableau-api

I have a saved twb workbook. I have a datasource connection to the database. It is an extract with filtered fields.

After the first save I do not know where the tde file is to share. I can't seem to save or change the location. According to this article
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/changing-the-file-path-for-extracts
 I do not have the extract field under Data on the datasource tab

[image]

Comment: If you don't create the extract in the data window but rather right click on the data source name in the sheet view, Tableau will ask you where to save it.

Comment: The right click menu from the sheet view worked. Do you want to write this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't create the extract in the data window but rather right click on the data source name in the sheet view, Tableau will ask you where to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving as a .twbx file so that the datasource is packaged with the workbook? If you are working with an extract the file would be help in the zipped workbook.